# Integration of Sentiment analysis in CRM

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

What is the process for integrating sentiment analysis in a CRM? What I am searching for is a system which analyzes the customer comments or reviews using the CRM and finds out the customer sentiment on the services provided by the system or company or a product.

I have done a sentiment analyzer which takes text and shows the sentiment of the text. Now I want to integrate the above-mentioned sentiment analyzer to a CRM, how can I do that?

Comment: This is surely going to depend 100% on the implementation of the CRM. Integration work involves understanding the specific system you are integrating with, and there is very little practical (in the "how to do it") that could be said about it in general, especially in the context of AI. If the CRM is completely outsourced and has an API that you are allowed to use, then the API docs are worth a look. Otherwise, your first task is probably to meet with the technology owner of the CRM system - within your own IT department or 3rd-party as appropriate for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I got one [paper](https://eprints.qut.edu.au/85084/1/Mohd%20Ridzwan_Yaakub_Thesis.pdf) on the integration of opinion mining in CRM, which helps to get an idea about the process involved.